# How ask more information about an answer?

Tags: support, comments

Yesterday, I read an interesting answer about drawing histogram in Android application. However, I didn't understand the use of two variables whose one is not initialize. So, I decided to add a comment to know the meaning of both variables. As I'm new on Stack Overflow, I cannot add a comment (I don't have any reputation), so I decided to add an answer but as it was more a question than an answer, it has been deleted.

How can I ask more information about an answer which seems to be incomplete? I have tried to search on Meta Stack Overflow but my English is not perfect, and it is difficult to find right key words.

Comment: Earn 50 rep and then comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if it is the only manner? I am not sure to have enough skills to earn some reputations.

Comment: @CodyGray All of those are about asking for clarification of the question, not an answer.

Comment: related: [Allow anyone to comment but hide low-rep users' comments until reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186954/allow-anyone-to-comment-but-hide-low-rep-users-comments-until-reviewed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your question hasn't been sufficiently answered in the original thread, it *might* be because you have a slightly different question. If that is the case, you should ask a separate question, possibly referring to the original to show what you've looked at and why the question/answers there are not relevant to your specific situation.

From what I can make of your description of the scenario, it appears this is the case, since your confusion is about a technique/usage that occurred incidentally in an answer you were reading. If the topic of the question wasn't about "the use of two variables whose one is not initialize", you should bring this up as a separate question (after checking to confirm the question has not already been asked on the site, of course).

If the question is in fact the same as the one you have, and you're simply having trouble understanding the answers, there's nothing for it but to gain 50 rep and post a comment.